# Can I sell properties in Monopoly with houses to another player ?

Tags: monopoly

Can I sell properties in Monopoly with houses to another player for a cost w/o mortgaging the property to the bank ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last bit about "w/o mortgaging."  You can't mortgage a property with houses on it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Unimproved properties, railroads and utilities (but not buildings) may be sold to any player as a private transaction for any amount the owner can get. However, no property can be sold to another player if buildings are standing on any properties of that colour-group. Any buildings so located must be sold back to the Bank before the owner can sell any property of that colour-group.
>
> Houses and Hotels may be sold back to the Bank at any time for one-half the price paid for them. All houses on one colour-group may be sold at once, or they may be sold one house at a time (one hotel equals five houses), evenly, in reverse of the manner in which they were erected.

From:
http://richard_wilding.tripod.com/monorules.htm#sellingproperty
The following page is a copy of the rules as printed in the Monopoly® Rule Book.

Comment: Rolled back latest edit, as it corrupted the quoted text. Quotes are what they are - and comments on the content must be kept separate from the quote itself.